# how to import function from a .js module to another .js module in node js, using express, ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, node-modules

Hi I am trying to import a function from a js file to another js file, the files are client side  in node js and therefore I cannot use the require method .
I cannot use the import statement unless I add type: module in package.json file and if i do, I have to find a way to import ejs as I cannot use require method adding type: module in package.json. Any advice??

Please find code of app.js below:

APP.JS

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const ejs = require("ejs");

app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack. the question is not clear. i can just add some examples that may help you.

```js
const getAlgoValue = (averageValue) => {
  let number = 3.5 / Math.pow(averageValue, 0.7) + 1.5;
  return number;
};

exports.getAlgoValue = getAlgoValue;
```

Here is a function that I `export` and I need to import it into another file to use it.

```js
const { getAlgoValue } = require('./getAlgo');
```

Hope that I helped you. some resource that can help [module.exports](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)